# How to retrieve formData sent via post from PHP?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have problem with retrieving formData (angularjs) via PHP. How i can get to uploaded file properties, ie. $myfile->name from php file?

Controller, Service and Directive looks like:

```
app.directive('fileModel', ['$parse', function ($parse) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
        var modelSetter = model.assign;

        element.bind('change', function(){
            scope.$apply(function(){
                modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
            });
        });
    }
};
}]);

app.service('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http) {
this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl){
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file);
    $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
        transformRequest: angular.identity,
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
    })
    .success(function(){

        console.log(file.name);
    })
    .error(function(){
    });
}
}]);

app.controller('uploadController', ['$scope', 'fileUpload', function($scope, fileUpload){

$scope.uploadFile = function(){
    var file = $scope.myFile;
    console.log('file is ' + JSON.stringify(file));
    var uploadUrl = 'json/file_upload';
    fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
};

}]);
```

Form:

```
<div ng-controller="uploadController">
    <input type="file" file-model="myFile"/>
    <button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
</div>
```

PHP file:

```
$myFile = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

It does't work. My question is... how i can get to file properties, ie. $myfile->name from PHP file?

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` ??

Comment: Have you tried `.success(function( json ) { console.log( json, json.data ); });`

Comment: `$_POST` - empty, `console.log(json)` - undefined. `console.log(file.name)` returns file name, but in PHP `$file = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);` is null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, problem solved :]

Directive, Service, Controller works fine - problem was on PHP side...

Proper form template:

```
<div ng-controller="uploadController">
    <input type="file" name="file" file-model="myFile"/>
    <button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
</div>
```

In this case:

```
$var = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

returns nothing, but:

```
$_FILES['file']['name']
```

this is were magic happens :]